# Android ActionBar: Show text on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my application i created a login session.
I've got an ActionBar with two icon, "home" and "login". I want to replace "login" with a string (Welcome Dude!, for example) after a successfull login.
I waked this way: if there's no user logged, an action bar is shown, with HOME and ICON items. When a user is logged, another action bar is shown. In this second action bar i'd like to have HOME item and a welcome message.

Is that possible?

I thought also to create an item and set its text when the login is successfull, but i can't do that.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. It works with ActionBarSherlock library:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    if(userIsLogged){
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_with_hello_string, menu);
    }
    else {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_with_login_button, menu);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

You just need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` when the user logs in.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Without doubts it will be helpful. But my problem is how to insert the string in my action bar and show it. My application already changes menu, but i don't know how to insert the string...